# How do I stop the program of doing an expression?

Tags: java, swing, calculator

I'm making an average grade calculator for my school. I'm doing it very simply in JavaSwing.  You have 7 textfields (which the classes) and you type in there your final grade. When you hit "Calculate" it computes the average grade based on a formula that my school uses.

My problem is that when someone types a number greater than 20 (max. grade) it shows a error dialog but then it still calculates the average grade and I just want it to show the error dialog.

Here's the code:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {



            double getValuePort = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
            double getValueIng = Double.parseDouble(textField_1.getText());
            double getValueFil = Double.parseDouble(textField_2.getText());
            double getValueEF = Double.parseDouble(textField_3.getText());
            double getValueHCA = Double.parseDouble(textField_4.getText());
            double getValueDes = Double.parseDouble(textField_5.getText());
            double getValuePT = Double.parseDouble(textField_6.getText());


            double getValueMedia = (3*(getValuePort+getValueIng+getValueFil+getValueEF+getValueHCA)/5+getValueDes+2*getValuePT)/6;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "A tua média é de: " + getValueMedia);
            System.out.println(getValueMedia);


            if (getValuePort > 20 || getValueIng > 20 || getValueFil > 20 || getValueEF > 20 ||
                    getValueHCA > 20 || getValueDes > 20 || getValuePT > 20) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "A nota não pode ser superior a 20!", "ERRO", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null);

            }

        }
```

Comment: Wouldn't putting the part where you calculate and show `getValueMedia` inside an `else`-block solve the problem? Also, consider using [`JSpinner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)s instead of textfields. This way you wouldn't even need to check that.

Comment: Maybe I'll use it. Perhaps I'll make two versions of the program just for fun. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the `getValueMedia()` calculation in an `else{}` block only following your `if()` condition to insure it is only executed if the `getValuePort` is a valid value.